# Hexadecimal representation of char read from file

Tags: c++

Here i want to print hexadecimal representation of char which i read from file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream f("inputfile");

    char ch;
    f.get(ch);

    cout << hex << (int) ch << endl;

    f.close();  
    return 0;
}
```

All inputfile has is one byte `0xab`

The output is: `ffffffab`

But if I add (unsigned char) before ch `cout << hex << (int) (unsigned char) ch << endl;` i have this output: `ab`

Why is it so? Where does these `ffffff` from in my first input? And why they are not in the second one?

Comment: In C (I assume it's the same in C++) the upper value limit for 8-bit `signed char` is 127, the hexadecimal value `0xab` has the value 171 which is greater than 127, so it is Undefined Behaviour to read that into a 8-bit `signed char`.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, a `char` is a signed number between -128 and 127 (8 bits). When you see `ab` in the file, this represents a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) number. Since the first bit is a 1, it is treated as a negative number. When you cast it to `int`, it is "sign extended" out to 32 bits, by prepending 1 bits (this is where all the `f`s come from, since that is a hex digit of all 1s). When you first cast it as an `unsigned char`, it is re-interpreted as a number between 0 and 255, since it is now interpreted as a positive number, casting to `int` prepends 0s, which are hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on compiler settings, but on most a `char` without qualifier is interpreted as signed by default.

Your `char` of value `0xAB (171)` now has value `0xAB (-85)`, which becomes 0xFFFFFFAB when promoted to `int`